# Checking if an ArrayList contains another ArrayList as element

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of lists and I would like to add a list to it, without duplicate. In other to do that, I would like to check if that list is already contained in the main list. I have written something like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test{
public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Main = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
  temp.add("One");
  temp.add("Two");
  temp.add("Three");
  Main.add(temp);// add this arraylist to the main array list
  ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();

  temp1.add("One");
  temp1.add("Two");
  temp1.add("Three");

  if(!Main.containsAll(temp1)) // check if temp1 is already in Main
   {
    Main.add(temp1);
   }
 }
}
```

When I print the contents of `Main`, I obtain both `temp` and `temp1`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should be doing `Main.add(new ArrayList<String>(temp));`. Directly adding temp would set a reference to the temp variable (object) and that's not something you'd want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're getting confused with the use of `containsAll` and the list of lists.

`containsAll` is a method that checks whether this collection contains all of the elements of the given collection. In this case:

- This collection has 1 element, which is a `List<String>`;
- The given collection has 3 elements, which are `"One`, `"Two"` and `"Three"`.

And clearly, this collection, which only contains a `List<String>` (which is `["First, "Two", "Three"]`), does *not* contain the 3 elements; it only contains a list of those three elements.

So what you really want here isn't `containsAll`, but `contains`, i.e. you want to check whether your list contains another list (and not its elements).

The following works:

```
if (!Main.contains(temp1)) {
   Main.add(temp1);
}
```

and will result in `Main` being `[[One, Two, Three]]`, added just once.

The side question is: why does it work? Well now, the question is: does my `List<List<String>>`, which is `[[One, Two, Three]]`, contains this `List<String>`, which is `[One, Two, Three]`? Since two lists are equal when they have the same size and all of their elements are equal, it does contain it.

Comment: perfect; that work perfectly. Thank you for the details

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`List#contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) since `contains` will check for instances of `ArrayList` that are equal to the provided `ArrayList` which will be the case here as `temp.equals(temp1)` returns `true` since the method `equals` of an `AbstractList` compares their content and here the content of those `ArrayList` is equal.

```
if(!Main.contains(temp1)) // check if temp1 is already in Main
{
    Main.add(temp1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to avoid duplicate lists (and not check for the elements of the inner lists), just use `Main.contains` instead of `Main.containsAll`.

This will check whether the `Main` list already contains a list with the elements you are about to add.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if it was about `ArrayList<Integer>`? There is such a method named `contains()`. To check if your main list contains some object (another list) just invoke this function passing it as the parameter.